# Error in building snap package on launchpad

Tags: launchpad, snap

I'm trying to create a snap build on launchpad for my application.

I'm able to build the application fine on launchpad normally, however the snap build is failing with the following error:

```
W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/snappy-dev/tools/ubuntu yakkety InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F1831DDAFC42E99D, E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/snappy-dev/tools/ubuntu yakkety InRelease' is not signed.
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the snapcraft.yaml that I have writted and added to launchpad : http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bablu-boy/nutty/trunk/view/head:/snapcraft.yaml

The snap build page on launchpad is [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~bablu-boy/+snap/nutty).The build log of the latest snap build has the above error.

Appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Looking at the previous build logs containing that error, it seems that you were building against yakkety. You should probably be building against xenial.

Comment: @Kylethanks for your suggestion. When I tried building against Xenial, I get this error: `Pulling granite 
bzr: ERROR: exceptions.ValueError: Invalid header value 'Basic U05BUEJVSUxELTUyOTMtMTQ3NDQ5NjQ2MzphMzY4NDYwN2I0ODU0NWIyODUwNTMyMzg5ZDFlYTNm\nMA=='` This probably looks like a snapcraft error.

Comment: Yeah, that's the bzr bug Colin mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit complicated, and I'm not sure I can resolve it for you on the spot.  You've found a bug.

Normally, Launchpad doesn't bother to ship out public keys for the archives it asks its builders to build against, since they're all in our datacentre on trusted networks.  This is maybe not ideal, but we configure `sbuild` to allow unauthenticated archives and so it usually only results in a cosmetic warning.

However, in this case, `snapcraft` is set up to borrow the build system's `apt` configuration in order to fetch the packages you've listed in `stage-packages`, and it doesn't seem to know to also borrow the configuration that allows unauthenticated archives.  Thus, things fail.

I think the best fix is probably to change Launchpad to ship the necessary public keys to the builders, at least for snap builds.  While it isn't strictly needed in most cases, the strange warning confuses people sometimes even when it doesn't cause a hard failure, and it would be a nice piece of hardening.  Please could you [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+filebug) about this?

Separately, I see that you're running into a [bzr bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1606203) when you tried to build against the primary archive, but at least that one is known and we should have it fixed fairly soon.

Update: This is finally all fixed now.  You'll need to change your `snapcraft.yaml` a bit for series later than xenial because they don't have `valac-0.30-vapi` (for yakkety, use `valac-0.32-vapi`, and for zesty, use `valac-0.34-vapi`; other changes may be needed), but that's all the kind of thing that you should be able to sort out in your build system.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanation. I will try to read through it properly and research a bit more to make sure I file the right bug for yaketty. When I build the snap against xenial, I am getting the bug you have mentioned for the Invalid header. I will stay tured to the bug to see when it is fixed and re-try the build again. Although the last response in the bug tracker looks like the fix has been released on 9th Sep, 2016 ?

Comment: Don't worry too much about researching a super-detailed bug report.  A reference to my explanation here would be fine.

The bzr bug has been fixed for yakkety, but not yet for xenial.

Comment: Thanks I have filed a bug here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1626739

Comment: Thanks Colin, I have filed a bug report here: [link] (https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1626739) https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1626739. Is there any build where I can build a snap - xenial and yaketty are out of scope for the present.

Comment: When I try to build the snap locally on my machine I get this error. Is this realted to the launchpad bug as well? `Pulling granite Permission denied (publickey). ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying Permission denied (publickey). bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist. Command '['bzr', 'branch', 'lp:granite/0.4', '/home/sid/Documents/Projects/snaps/nutty/parts/granite/src']' returned non-zero exit status 3`

Comment: No, that's some other problem, perhaps not having an SSH key set up that's registered with Launchpad or something like that.  Definitely unrelated to anything that happens when Launchpad is building things itself, at any rate.

Comment: I removed my PGP key on launchpad and re-added it, but still could not resolve the error. I ended up putting the code on GitHub and providing the git url in the snapcraft.yaml which builds the snap without issues.